# PyCharm. Подключение BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pycharm, beautiful-soup

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку BeautifulSoup. Скачал библиотеку. Поискал в гугле как её установить через cmd установил. Судя по видео из примера установка прошла успешно.
В примере у меня написано как сделать импорт:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Но у меня выдаёт ошибку что bs4 не найден.

Как к PyCharm подключить эту библиотеку?

Comment: У вас один питон стоит на компьютере? Посмотрите в пичарме в пути: `File/Settings/Project:.../Project Interpreter` там в комбобоксе выбор будет интерпретаторов. Убедитесь что там стоит нужный вам и что в его модулях будет `beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Посмотрел в настройках у меня в настройках два интерпритатора 3.5 и 3.6. Я работал под 3.5. В списке пакетов beautifulsoup4 нет. А у 3.6 есть. Переключил на 3.6 но под ним почему то не работает отладка. Кнопки выполнения кода не активны.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках нажмите кнопочку, и будет Вам счастье.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы устанавливать пакеты сразу в Pycharm рекомендуем использовать встроенный терминал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотите использовать библиотеки через Windows зайдите в настройке и добавьте эту библиотеку вручную или выберете в настройках интерпретатора System Intepritator.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]